# Notes underneath the bar line

Tags: piano, sheet-music, pitch

I am new to sheet music and.I get the notes in the lines and on the lines. But when the notes go above or below the line  I have a hard time with reading it and identify were the notes corresponded to the keys. I also am not very fast with reading the notes

Comment: If you're not good at something, you need to practise it. What is your question?

Comment: Just checking that you *understand* how [ledger lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledger_line) work. They're just like the lines of the staff; as you go up or down in pitch you put alternate putting notes "on" a line or "between" lines, but if a note is "between" lines you don't bother drawing the "outside" line.

Comment: Bar lines are _vertical_ lines; is this question asking about notes above or below bar Iines? Or about notes going underneath the _horizontal_ stave/staff lines?